# Patterns of synthesis of all the variations of ～とまではいかないが

Tags: grammar, expressions

During my time studying Japanese, I have come across many variations of the ～とまではいかないが (even if not) pattern, which are as follows.

1. ～とまではいかないが
2. ～とまではいかないとしても
3. ～とまではいかないにしても
4. ～とまではいかないまでも
5. ～とまではいかなくても
6. ～とまではいかなくとも
7. ～とまではいかずとも
8. ～ところまではいかずとも
9. ～とはいかないまでも
10. ～とはいかないにしても

**I would like to know in the first place if these are all the possible variations of the ～とまではいかないが pattern**, as I would prefer to discover and learn them all at once and not in dribs and drabs as till now.

Besides, I have tried to compress all these variations into a few patterns in order to have a simpler, but at the same time complete structuring of all these variations in my head.

～｛とは・とはまでは・ところ（は）・ところ（は）までは｝いかない｛が・としても・にしても・までも｝

～｛とは・とはまでは・ところ（は）・ところ（は）までは｝いかなく｛ても・とも｝

～｛とは・とはまでは・ところ（は）・ところ（は）までは｝いかず｛ても・とも｝

**Would these patterns of synthesis of all the variations of ～とまではいかないが be correct and complete?**

If possible, I would like you to help me to correct and modify them as necessary so that they collect all the variations in the simplest possible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These expressions (1 to 10) are all correct, but you've "compressed" them incorrectly.

- とはまでは and ところはまでは are wrong. Why use two contrastive は's?
- ところはいかないが is wrong. You have to use まで and say ところ**まで**はいかないが.
- いかずても is wrong. This must always be いかずとも.

Also note that these can be easily split into more basic rules and patterns, and I can easily think of many other variations  including とまでいかないにしたって, とまで言うわけでもないが, とまではいくといえなくとも, とまでじゃなくても and とまでは言わね[ど](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/98918/5010). I felt the same thing when you asked [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/98498/5010), but there are countless combinations, so you should stop trying to "compress" them halfway and memorize them all.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for pointing out my mistakes. It helped a lot. About trying to create a syntactic scheme to form patterns, it's because for me, trying to memorize different variations that come out from time to time without any (apparent) logic in the end comes to nothing.

Comment: In order to understand patterns better and be able not only to use the ones I've seen, but also to create new ones as you have done in your answer, I do really need to parse patterns as I have done in my synthesis, and for each part, to see all the different elements I can use. At least for me, that is what I find the most helpful.